# how to share the data between the views in angular

Tags: angularjs

i am doing one angular project in which i am loading the new view by calling the function . up to this thing it is fine . now the my requirement is i want some data to transferred to the new view from the same same function . using the same controller . i am showing here the demo code.

```js
$scope.passID = function(id){
    console.log(id);
    $state.go("view", {id: $scope.id });
}
```

Comment: Use a factory to store common values you want to share and inject it in controllers of whatever views you want

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same controller, the `$scope` variables can be accessed in both views. But, if you have 2 views with 2 `controllers`, it is possible to share the `$scope` variables(data) between `controllers` through **services** and **factory**.But, the `$scope` variables are local to the `controller` itself so set the data to the service or factory to know about that particular variable.I prefer using factory, easy and smooth as butter. If you are using the service of factory in a separate file you need to include the file in `index.html`.

```
   app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, myService, $state) {
    $scope.variable1 = "One";
    myService.set($scope.variable1);
    $state.go('app.thepagewhereyouwanttoshare'); //go to the page where you want to share that variable.
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, myService) {
    console.log("shared variable " + myService.get());
});
.factory('myService', function() {
    function set(data) {
        products = data;
    }

    function get() {
        return products;
    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }

})
```